# ¿Cómo encontrar un objeto en un array en base al valor de un atributo?

Tags: javascript

Muy buenas,
Supongamos que tenemos una clase Automovil con las propiedades placa, marca y color. Si en un array tenemos 50 instancias de esa clase

¿habría alguna herramienta que permitiese obtener todos los datos de un objeto conociendo solo su placa?

Y si no ¿Cómo pensáis que sería el modo más adecuado de hacerlo?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Ayudaría mucho si por favor agregas tu código

Comment: Hola @Aprendiz, no hay código. Es una suposición

solo pregunto si existe alguna herramienta para ese caso o, si no, cómo se plantearía

Comment: Por ejemplo, había pensado en crear un listado con toda la información de los objetos y así, si solo introduzco la placa, obtener el nombre del objeto

Comment: Te recomendaría leer [ask], pues me parece basada en opiniones, por eso te recomendaba lo del código

Comment: Si quieres una buena respuesta, aumenta la calidad de tu pregunta. Ve a [ask] para más información... Respecto a lo solicitado, no existe una función mágica que te resuelva todo, sería bueno que crees una de cero con todo lo que pides... Ahí es donde se debería tener tu código(aunque digas que no hay) ya que nadie te hará el trabajo así porque sí. Siempre se necesita partir de algo

Comment: Solo preguntaba si había alguna herramienta. Konamiman me ha respondido perfecta y amablemente

Muchas gracias por todo

Comment: La pregunta puede que no tenga la mejor redacción posible, pero al final se reduce a "cómo encontrar un objeto en un array en base al valor de un atributo", que es algo totalmente legítimo para preguntar en este sitio. Me parece exagerado votarla negativo o incluso para cerrarla.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si tienes un array de objetos que representan automóviles y quieres encontrar el objeto con una determinada matrícula, puedes usar [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
vehiculos.filter(v => v.matricula == "1234ABC");
```

No obstante, si sabes de antemano que la matrícula va a actuar como identificador único de los objetos, es más eficiente (y el código quedará más claro) si en vez de un array de objetos compones desde el principio un objeto cuyas claves sean las matrículas y los valores sean los objetos:

```
vehiculos = {
   "1234ABC": { ... },
   "5678XYZ": { ... },
   ...
}
```

De esta forma puedes encontrar tu objeto simplemente con `vehiculos["1234ABC"]`.

Comment: Muchas gracias Konamiman,
Muy amable por tu respuesta. Muy bien explicado

:D